# error while compiling a new custom module in ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, lager

I am trying to compile a custom module and continuously getting this error

```
`undefined parse transform 'lager_transform'`
```

I tried almost all the suggestions regarding this error but could not come across anything.
I am using ejabberd-18.01 and otp 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you include [logger.hrl](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/include/logger.hrl) file. When compiler finds `-compile([{parse_transform, lager_transform}]).` [here](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/18.01/include/logger.hrl#L22) it calls `lager_transform:parse_transform/2` for making new module. `lager_transform` gets source code (Erlang AST or Abstract Syntax Tree) and produces new AST which contains some code for generating log information.
The problem is that your compiler can't find `lager_transform.beam` for running that function. You can give path of `lager` to compiler using `-pa` or `-pz` flag:

```
# I included `logger.hrl`
$ erlc test.erl
test.erl: undefined parse transform 'lager_transform'

# Find path of lager's ebin in your system for below command
$ erlc -pa /opt/ejabberd-18.01/lib/lager-3.2.1/ebin/ test.erl
# done
```